# Button is overlapping the text in Outlook for Windows emails

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, html-email

I'm new to HTML emails and there is an issue I'm struggling with for a couple of days.
I have a two column layout with an image on the left side and some text and a button on the right side.
The issue seems to be the combination of vertical alignment of the column and the alignment of the button itself. The column's alignment can be top, middle, or bottom and the button's alignment can be left, center, or right. If the column's alignment is `valign="middle"` and the button's alignment is `align="left"` or `align="right"`, the button overlaps the text. It seems the the issue is on Outlook for Windows as it looks fine on Outlook for Mac.

Here's how it looks on Outlook for Windows-
[image]

Here's how it is on Outlook for Mac (this is what I expect on Windows)
[image]
Here's the entire email code-

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="x-apple-disable-message-reformatting" />
    <meta name="viewport" content=" width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <title>sdf</title>
    <!--[if gte mso 9]>
      <xml>
        <o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
          <o:AllowPNG /> <o:PixelsPerInch>96</o:PixelsPerInch>
        </o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
      </xml>
    <![endif]-->
    <style type="text/css" data-premailer="ignore">
      @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
        @-ms-viewport {
          width: 320px;
        }
      }
    </style>
    <style type="text/css" data-premailer="ignore">
      .ExternalClass,
      .FullW,
      .ReadMsgBody {
        width: 100% !important;
      }
      form td,
      form th,
      table th {
        padding: 0;
      }
      html,
      table th {
        margin: 0 !important;
      }
      html {
        padding: 0 !important;
      }
      button {
        display: block !important;
      }
      div {
        display: block;
      }
      .ExternalClass * {
        line-height: 100%;
      }
      .ExternalClass,
      .ExternalClass div,
      .ExternalClass font,
      .ExternalClass p,
      .ExternalClass span,
      .ExternalClass td,
      .ExternalClass th,
      img {
        line-height: 100% !important;
      }
      .ReadMsgBody .ExternalClass a:link,
      .ii a,
      .yshortcuts {
        text-decoration: none !important;
        color: transparent !important;
      }
      a[x-apple-data-detectors] {
        color: inherit !important;
        text-decoration: none !important;
        font-size: inherit !important;
        font-family: inherit !important;
        font-weight: inherit !important;
        line-height: inherit !important;
      }
      table,
      td,
      th {
        mso-table-lspace: 0;
        mso-table-rspace: 0;
        border-collapse: collapse;
      }
      a,
      blockquote,
      body,
      li,
      p,
      span,
      table,
      td,
      th {
        -ms-text-size-adjust: 100% !important;
        -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100% !important;
      }
      table th {
        vertical-align: top;
        font-weight: 400;
      }
      a img,
      img {
        border: none !important;
        outline: 0 !important;
        text-decoration: none !important;
      }
      img {
        -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic !important;
      }
      .imgfix {
        line-height: 0 !important;
        font-size: 0 !important;
      }
      .imgfix div img,
      .imgfix img {
        margin: 0 !important;
        padding: 0;
      }
      a {
        color: #000;
        text-decoration: none;
      }
      html {
        overflow-x: hidden;
      }
    </style>
    <!--[if gte mso 9]>
      <style type="text/css" data-premailer="ignore">
        .imgfix img {
          mso-line-height-rule: exactly;
          font-size: 1px;
          line-height: 100%;
        }
        .text .padding,
        .button-link td,
        .list-item span,
        .menu-item span,
        .icon-menu-item span {
          line-height: 120%;
        }
        [style*="Lato"],
        [style*="Merriweather Sans"],
        [style*="Open Sans"],
        [style*="Roboto"],
        [style*="Source Sans Pro"],
        [style*="DM Sans"] {
          font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif !important;
        }
        [style*="Arvo"],
        [style*="Lora"],
        [style*="Merriweather"],
        [style*="Noticia Text"],
        [style*="Playfair Display"] {
          font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif !important;
        }
      </style>
    <![endif]-->
    <style type="text/css" data-premailer="ignore">
      ::-webkit-scrollbar {
        width: 8px;
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
        -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
      }
      ::-webkit-scrollbar:hover {
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09);
      }
      ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:vertical {
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
        -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
      }
    </style>
    <style type="text/css">
      @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
        .m-show-row {
          max-height: initial !important;
          max-width: 100% !important;
          opacity: initial !important;
          mso-hide: none !important;
          display: table !important;
        }
        .m-show-row table {
          max-height: initial !important;
          max-width: 100% !important;
          opacity: initial !important;
          mso-hide: none !important;
          display: table !important;
        }
        .m-show-row tr {
          max-height: initial !important;
          max-width: 100% !important;
          opacity: initial !important;
          mso-hide: none !important;
          display: table !important;
        }
        .m-show-row th {
          max-height: initial !important;
          max-width: 100% !important;
          opacity: initial !important;
          mso-hide: none !important;
          display: table-cell !important;
        }
        .m-show-row td {
          max-height: initial !important;
          max-width: 100% !important;
          opacity: initial !important;
          mso-hide: none !important;
          display: table-cell !important;
        }
        .m-show-row div {
          max-height: initial !important;
          max-width: 100% !important;
          opacity: initial !important;
          mso-hide: none !important;
        }
        .m-show-row span {
          max-height: initial !important;
          max-width: 100% !important;
          opacity: initial !important;
          mso-hide: none !important;
        }
        .m-show-row img {
          max-height: initial !important;
          max-width: 100% !important;
          opacity: initial !important;
          mso-hide: none !important;
        }
        .m-show-row a {
          max-height: initial !important;
          max-width: 100% !important;
          opacity: initial !important;
          mso-hide: none !important;
          display: block !important;
        }
        .m-show-row.regular .column {
          display: block !important;
        }
        .m-show-row .text div {
          display: block !important;
        }
        .m-show-row .text span,
        .m-show-row .text a {
          display: initial !important;
        }
        .m-show-row .menu .menu-item.m-hide {
          display: none !important;
        }
        .m-show-row .menu .menu-item.m-show {
          display: block !important;
        }
        .m-show-row .icon-menu .icon-menu-item.m-block,
        .m-show-row .icon-menu tr.m-block {
          display: block !important;
        }
        .m-show-row .icon-menu .m-hide {
          display: none !important;
        }
        .menu .menu-items {
          display: block !important;
        }
        .menu .menu-item.m-show {
          max-height: initial !important;
          max-width: 100% !important;
          opacity: initial !important;
          mso-hide: none !important;
          padding: 10px 0 !important;
        }
        .menu .menu-item.m-show span,
        .menu .menu-item.m-show a,
        .menu .menu-item.m-show div {
          max-height: initial !important;
          max-width: 100% !important;
          opacity: initial !important;
          mso-hide: none !important;
          display: block !important;
        }
        .icon-menu-item.icon-text span {
          display: inline-block !important;
        }
        .icon-menu img {
          max-width: 100% !important;
        }
        .icon-menu tr.m-show {
          max-height: initial !important;
          max-width: 100% !important;
          opacity: initial !important;
          mso-hide: none !important;
        }
        .icon-menu tr.m-show .icon-menu-item * {
          display: block !important;
          max-height: initial !important;
          max-width: 100% !important;
          opacity: initial !important;
          mso-hide: none !important;
        }
        .icon-menu tr.m-show .icon-menu-item,
        .icon-menu tr.m-show .icon-menu-item td {
          display: inline-block !important;
          max-height: initial !important;
          max-width: 100% !important;
          opacity: initial !important;
          mso-hide: none !important;
        }
        .list {
          width: 100% !important;
        }
        .list table {
          width: 100% !important;
        }
        .list .m-list-item {
          display: block !important;
          max-height: unset !important;
          max-height: initial !important;
          max-width: 100% !important;
          opacity: initial !important;
          mso-hide: none !important;
        }
        .list .m-list-item span,
        .list .m-list-item a,
        .list .m-list-item div {
          display: table-cell !important;
          max-height: initial !important;
          max-width: 100% !important;
          opacity: initial !important;
          mso-hide: none !important;
        }
        .list .m-list-item .decorator {
          padding-right: 3px !important;
        }
        .m-block,
        .m-show {
          display: block !important;
        }
        .m-inline-block {
          display: inline-block !important;
        }
        .m-vertical-spacing {
          padding-bottom: 10px !important;
        }
        .m-table {
          display: table !important;
        }
        .m-inline {
          display: inline !important;
        }
        .m-full-width {
          width: 100% !important;
        }
        .m-half-width {
          width: 50% !important;
        }
        .m-align-center {
          text-align: center !important;
        }
        .body-padding {
          padding: 0 !important;
        }
        .body-text {
          max-height: unset !important;
        }
        tr {
          width: 100% !important;
          display: table !important;
        }
        .row {
          height: auto !important;
        }
        table.menu td,
        table.menu th {
          width: 100% !important;
        }
        .button-link a {
          border-radius: 5px !important;
          display: block !important;
          padding: 10px 20px !important;
          box-sizing: border-box !important;
        }
        .image img {
          max-width: 100% !important;
        }
        .menu .menu-spacing,
        .list .list-type,
        .list .list-item,
        .m-hide {
          display: none !important;
        }
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body
    bgcolor="#f2f2f2"
    style="
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      line-height: 1;
      background-color: #f2f2f2;
    "
  >
    <div
      align="center"
      class="preheader"
      style="
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        color: #303030;
        display: none;
        font-size: 1px;
        line-height: 1px;
        max-height: 0;
        max-width: 0;
        opacity: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        mso-hide: all;
      "
    >
      sdf
    </div>
    <table
      class="container m-full-width"
      width="100%"
      bgcolor="#f2f2f2"
      border="0"
      cellpadding="0"
      cellspacing="0"
      title=""
      style="
        border-spacing: 0;
        text-align: center;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #f2f2f2;
      "
    >
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td
            class="body-padding"
            align="center"
            style="text-align: left; font-weight: 400; padding: 20px 0"
          >
            <table
              class="center border m-full-width"
              align="center"
              border="0"
              cellpadding="0"
              cellspacing="0"
              bgcolor="#ffffff"
              style="
                border-spacing: 0;
                border-collapse: separate;
                width: 600px;
                background-color: #fff;
                border-radius: 0;
              "
              width="600"
            >
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td style="text-align: left; font-weight: 400">
                    <table
                      class="row regular m-full-width"
                      border="0"
                      cellspacing="0"
                      cellpadding="0"
                      style="
                        border-spacing: 0;
                        text-align: center;
                        width: 100%;
                        border: 0;
                      "
                    >
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          <td style="text-align: left; font-weight: 400">
                            <table
                              class="row table"
                              border="0"
                              cellpadding="0"
                              cellspacing="0"
                              style="
                                border-spacing: 0;
                                text-align: center;
                                width: 100%;
                                border: 0;
                              "
                            >
                              <tbody>
                                <tr class="table" style="width: 100%">
                                  <th
                                    class="column m-full-width m-table m-table"
                                    bgcolor=""
                                    valign="middle"
                                    style="
                                      font-weight: 400;
                                      border-collapse: separate;
                                      text-align: center;
                                      width: 348px;
                                      vertical-align: middle;
                                    "
                                    width="348"
                                  >
                                    <table
                                      class="image"
                                      border="0"
                                      cellspacing="0"
                                      cellpadding="0"
                                      style="border-spacing: 0; width: 100%"
                                    >
                                      <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                          <td
                                            class="padding"
                                            align="center"
                                            style="
                                              font-weight: 400;
                                              padding: 0;
                                              text-align: center;
                                            "
                                          >
                                            <a
                                              class="imgfix"
                                              target="_blank"
                                              style="
                                                display: block;
                                                text-decoration: none;
                                              "
                                              ><img
                                                class="m-inline m-full-width"
                                                border="0"
                                                src="https://images-stage.apsis.cloud/804df07c-3e81-4f8a-8518-182572b51512.jpeg"
                                                alt=""
                                                title=""
                                                width="348"
                                                style="width: 348px"
                                            /></a>
                                          </td>
                                        </tr>
                                      </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                  </th>
                                  <th
                                    class="column m-full-width m-table m-table"
                                    bgcolor=""
                                    valign="middle"
                                    style="
                                      font-weight: 400;
                                      border-collapse: separate;
                                      text-align: center;
                                      width: 252px;
                                      vertical-align: middle;
                                    "
                                    width="252"
                                  >
                                    <table
                                      class="text"
                                      border="0"
                                      cellspacing="0"
                                      cellpadding="0"
                                      style="border-spacing: 0; width: 100%"
                                    >
                                      <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                          <td
                                            class="padding"
                                            style="
                                              text-align: left;
                                              font-weight: 400;
                                              mso-line-height-rule: exactly;
                                              word-break: break-word;
                                              word-wrap: break-word;
                                              overflow-wrap: break-word;
                                              padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
                                              font: 14px/1.4 Arial, Helvetica,
                                                sans-serif;
                                            "
                                          >
                                            A das observantia non est recedendu
                                            vitae dictum. Gallia atilitatis,
                                            obscuris et malesuada fames.
                                          </td>
                                        </tr>
                                      </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                    <table
                                      class="button auto btn-radius"
                                      border="0"
                                      cellpadding="0"
                                      cellspacing="0"
                                      align="left"
                                      style="
                                        border-spacing: 0;
                                        border-collapse: separate;
                                        border-radius: 0;
                                      "
                                    >
                                      <tbody>
                                        <tr style="border-collapse: inherit">
                                          <td
                                            class="padding"
                                            style="
                                              font-weight: 400;
                                              text-align: center;
                                              border-radius: 0;
                                              padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
                                            "
                                          >
                                            <table
                                              class="button-link"
                                              align="left"
                                              border="0"
                                              cellpadding="0"
                                              cellspacing="0"
                                              style="
                                                border-spacing: 0;
                                                border-collapse: separate;
                                                color: #fff;
                                                border-radius: 0;
                                                background: #4a4a4a;
                                                font: bold 14px/1.4 Arial,
                                                  Helvetica, sans-serif;
                                              "
                                            >
                                              <tbody>
                                                <tr
                                                  style="
                                                    border-collapse: inherit;
                                                  "
                                                >
                                                  <td
                                                    style="
                                                      font-weight: 400;
                                                      text-align: center;
                                                      line-height: 1.4;
                                                      word-break: break-word;
                                                      word-wrap: break-word;
                                                      overflow-wrap: break-word;
                                                      padding: 10px 10px 10px
                                                        10px;
                                                      font: bold 14px/1.4 Arial,
                                                        Helvetica, sans-serif;
                                                    "
                                                  >
                                                    <!--[if gte mso 9]><a target="_blank" style="color:#ffffff"><span style="font:bold 14px/1.4 Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;"><[endif]-->button<!--[if gte mso 9]></span></a><[endif]-->
                                                  </td>
                                                </tr>
                                              </tbody>
                                            </table>
                                          </td>
                                        </tr>
                                      </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                  </th>
                                </tr>
                              </tbody>
                            </table>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

I also created a Codepen [here](https://codepen.io/rajatkhare/pen/jOKePqM).

I'm thinking it may have something to do with the button's align property as it is the same as `float:left` or `float:right` which removes the button from normal document flow.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why would you add such an incredible amount of <head> styling if you are going to use inline styling anyways? I feel as if you've done so much that you got lost in your own code.

Comment: Actually, this is not my code at all. It was written before I joined and I agree it's a mess. I honestly don't know why they wrote it this way.

Comment: In that case I suggest you remove all of the <head> styling and inline styling and start from scratch. There's no use in trying to figure out a problem caused by someone else if it is a mess like this, it's way more efficient to just start over and write the minimum amount of code required to fullfil your needs.  If you happen to stumble upon the same problem again, it will be way more easier to figure out what went wrong.

Comment: Unfortunately, it may take months to rewrite the entire codebase (the emails are dynamically generated based on drag and drop user inputs), and I don't have the time for that.

Comment: @KayAngevare email templates usually need both head styling and inline styling to cater for all the different email clients - some only read inline whilst others only read head (but not sure if that's still the case as that was a few years ago)

Comment: @Rajat, that's a wrong mindset. You're basically saying "We prefer to keep dealing with these kinds of superficial problems instead of figuring out how to solve the fundamental problems." Not going through the trouble to solve legacy problems is setting yourself and your company up for doomsday scenario's.

And Pete: it still is troublesome to write HTML for emails, but for these simple kind of emails there shouldn't be much trouble.

Comment: I'd like to do it, but I'm not the decision maker. The higher-ups wouldn't want me to spend months on rewriting the entire thing if it can be fixed sooner.

Comment: Then your higher-ups should be reprimanded for such short-sightedness. They seem very inexperienced in tech management according to the information you're providing.

Answer (score 2):

Anyhow, here's basically all the HTML you'd need for this, taking into account limitations of the different e-mail clients as well (thus only using accepted CSS).

```html
   <style>
     
     body{
      background-color:#f2f2f2;  
     }
     
     .tableCenter{
       border-collapse:collapse;
       margin:auto; 
       max-width:600px; 
       background-color:white;
       font-family: 'Arial', 'Helvetica', sans-serif;
       font-weight:400;
       line-height:20px;
       font-size:15px;
     }
     
     
     .tableCenter button{
       color:white;
       padding:10px;
       border:none;
       font-weight:bold;
       background:rgb(128, 128, 128);
     }
   </style>
   
   <table class='tableCenter'>
     <tr>
       <td style='width:55%'>
         <img src='https://images-stage.apsis.cloud/804df07c-3e81-4f8a-8518-182572b51512.jpeg' width='100%'>
       </td>
       <td style='width:40%; padding:20px'>
         <p>
         A das observantia non est recedendu vitae dictum. Gallia atilitatis, obscuris et malesuada fames.
         </p>
         
         <button>Button</button>
       </td>
     </tr>
   </table>
```

Comment: I see you've not used any alignment properties here. But the tool I'm working on allows to set valign on the container (containing the text and button) to place the content at the top, middle or bottom, and also align on the button to place it on the left or right. I wanted to know how to deal with that.